# Get data from a JSON output using 'jq'

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

I have the following JSON output:

```
{
  "201110131738QP27N": {
    "parent": 17,
    "name": "CentralServer",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 6
  },
  "201803271459ICV69": {
    "name": "subaccount1",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 1
  },
  "2018032715008ZM2G": {
    "name": "subaccount2",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 1
  },
  "201803281536PSKR4": {
    "name": "Este e um teste",
    "status": "Active"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to get only the following data:

```
201110131738QP27N
201803271459ICV69
2018032715008ZM2G
201803281536PSKR4
```

To get the desired data, I'm trying to use the `jq` command, but so far I have not succeeded.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. You mentioned you attempted this task using `jq`, but you did not provide your attempt. Could you please update your question to show your attempt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the raw output without an array use `|.[]` to unwrap it

```
jq --raw-output 'keys | .[]'  input.json
```

produces

```
201110131738QP27N
201803271459ICV69
2018032715008ZM2G
201803281536PSKR4
```

or more simply written as just `jq --raw-output 'keys[]'`

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way I can enter the contents of the key name and jq gives me the KeyID?
For example:
I inform "subaccount1" on the command and jq returns me 201803271459ICV69"

Comment: @RafaelBrianeziDaSilva: You need to ask it as a different question with your efforts

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`keys` builtin function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions#keys,keys_unsorted) of `jq`.

Assuming your input JSON is stored in the file `input.json`:

```
$ cat input.json | jq 'keys'
```

produces:

```
[
  "201110131738QP27N",
  "201803271459ICV69",
  "2018032715008ZM2G",
  "201803281536PSKR4"
]
```

Comment: Note that `keys` sorts the key names; if you want the unsorted listing, use `keys_unsorted` instead.